# Multivariable delta-epsilon limit proof

Tags: limits, multivariable-calculus, epsilon-delta

Prove using the delta epsilon definition that

$$
L = \lim_{(x,y)\rightarrow (0,0)}\frac{x^5e^{xy}}{x^2+e^y}=0
$$

What I have done so far:
$$\left | \frac{x^5e^{xy}}{x^2+e^y}-0 \right |< \epsilon  \;\;\;\;\;\;\;\;\;\;\;\;\;\;\; 0<\sqrt{x^2+y^2}<\delta$$

Then
$$
\left | \frac{x^5e^{xy}}{x^2+e^y}-0 \right |=\left | \frac{x^5e^{xy}}{x^2+e^y} \right |\leq \left | \frac{x^5e^{xy}}{x^2} \right |=\left | x^3 \right |\left | e^{xy} \right |=...
$$

And this is where I get stuck, how should I proceed?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Note that for $|x|,|y|<1$ you have that $|e^{xy}|<e$ and $|x^3|\leq|x^2|\leq|x^2+y^2|$.

Can you proceed, choosing $\delta$ small enough so that the given expression is less than $\epsilon$?

Comment: Now

$e\left | x^2+y^2 \right |\leq e\left | x+y \right |=e\sqrt{x^2+y^2}<e\delta $

Thus

$e\delta =\epsilon\Rightarrow \delta=\frac{\epsilon}{e}$

Is this correct?

Comment: It is not true that $|x+y|=\sqrt{x^2+y^2}$. But since the inequality still holds, the final answer itself is true.

Answer (score 2):

Be careful!  You will also want to take limit along $x=0$ too so you shouldn't leave $x^2$ alone in the denominator.

Instead, look at
$$
\left\lvert\frac{x^5 e^{xy}}{x^2+e^y}\right\rvert \leq 
\frac{\lvert x^5 e^{xy}\rvert}{e^y}=\lvert x^5\rvert\cdot e^{(x-1)y}
$$
where the inequality comes from $e^y>0$ and $x^2\geq 0$.

Answer (score 0):

$$
L = \lim_{(x,y)\rightarrow (0,0)}\frac{x^5e^{xy}}{x^2+e^y}=0
$$

Now
$$\left | \frac{x^5e^{xy}}{x^2+e^y}-0 \right |< \epsilon  \;\;\;\;\;\;\;\;\;\;\;\;\;\;\; 0<\sqrt{x^2+y^2}<\delta$$

Then
$$
\left | \frac{x^5e^{xy}}{x^2+e^y}-0 \right |=\left | \frac{x^5e^{xy}}{x^2+e^y} \right |\leq \left | \frac{x^5e^{xy}}{e^y} \right |=\left | x^5 \right |e^{(x-1)y}
$$

$$
<\left | x^5 \right |e\leq \left | x^2 \right |e\leq \left | x^2+y^2 \right |e\leq \left | x+y \right |e
$$
$$
\leq e\sqrt{x^2+y^2}<e\delta 
$$
Thus

$$
e\delta=\epsilon \Rightarrow \delta=\frac{\epsilon}{e}
$$